# When to exit when using nested open() functions?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I encountered some problems in the use of PhantomJS. I refer to [this article](https://nicolas.perriault.net/code/2012/introducing-casperjs-toolkit-phantomjs/). I tried to nest `open()` functions, but I did not get the results I want namely opening all 4 urls and printing all 4 `console.log`s.

code :

```
var page = require('webpage').create();             //新建一个页面

url1 = "-----";
url2 = "-----";
url3 = "-----";
url4 = "http://-----/";

page.open(url1, function(status) {                  //导航到第一个URL
    console.log('111111111111');
    if (status == "fail") phantom.exit();           //如果发生错误,退出程序
    page.open(url2, function(status) {              //否则在页面加载完成的回调函数中继续导航到第二个URL,依次类推
        console.log('22222222222222');
        if (status == "fail") phantom.exit();
        page.open(url3, function(status) {
            console.log('3333333333333333');
            if (status == "fail") phantom.exit();
            page.open(url4, function(status) {
                console.log('444444444444444');
                if (status == "fail") phantom.exit();
            });
        });
    });
    console.log('close');
    phantom.exit();
});
```

result:

```
$ phantomjs test.js 
111111111111
close
```

Comment: I like how there is a diagonal character free line in the code.

Comment: @sanki I think it would have to perform each output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to `exit` PhantomJS when you're done executing it and it seems that you are done after you `open` `url4`:

```
page.open(url1, function(status) {
    console.log('111111111111');
    if (status == "fail") phantom.exit();
    page.open(url2, function(status) {
        console.log('22222222222222');
        if (status == "fail") phantom.exit();
        page.open(url3, function(status) {
            console.log('3333333333333333');
            if (status == "fail") phantom.exit();
            page.open(url4, function(status) {
                console.log('444444444444444');
                if (status == "fail") phantom.exit();
                console.log('close');
                phantom.exit();
            });
        });
    });
});
```

PhantomJS is asynchronous just as Nicolas says in his blog. You're just exiting too early.

Comment: oh， tanks you. I made a mistake

Comment: Sorry，I have a new problem. PhantomJS is asynchronous, How to open multiple open () function? I open both, but only one execution

Comment: What do you mean? The above code opens every one of the URLs one after the other. Do you have errors? Maybe the page cannot be loaded.

Comment: hi， Because it is another new problem，  So I put here.[link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26835808/phantomjs-using-open-function-to-open-multiple-pages[/link]